# Выделить добавление новой строки в DataGrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Дело в том, что необходимо как-то выделить новую строку, куда пользователь записывает новые данные. Она как-то непонятно выглядит. Можно как-то имено эту строку расскрасить или может быть ещё что? И вот вопрос: как задать контент в поле в новой строке по умолчанию  и чтобы этот контент был там даже тогда, когда пользователь ещё не нажал на строку для добавления данных? Чтобы пользователю было понятно, что эти данных вводить не нужно и нажимать на это поле тоже нет необходимости. Заранее спасибо.